# Cannot get rid of this comma on the bottom of html. I am using react and in the index.html I don't see it there or in any of my components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image][image]

In photo on the bottom there is a comma and in dev tools it shows up in the root div but in the actual html and all components I can't find it.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it. Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: For starters, you can add your code so we can troubleshoot faster. Don't add all of it, just a [mcve]

Comment: maybe it's in the index.html

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue in React and located it in my index.js file. There was an extra comma right next to my `<App />` component. After deleting, the comma was gone.

Initially:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store} >
    < App />,
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

After:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store} >
    < App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we can deduce from the image is that the comma is definitely outside the first `div` with `className="container"` so you only have to look at everything outside the first div and before the end of `</App>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1
(First go to your root file index.js)
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>,
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

solution :- remove the comma from </Provider>,.
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```